# How to align axis labels to axes in plot3 in groupplots in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, groupplots

The default direction of axes labels is horizontal, but I want to change it to parallel to the axes in 3D plots. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            horizontal sep=2cm,
        },
        enlarge x limits=true,
        every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
        width=7cm,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize first figure},xlabel={x1 label},ylabel={y1 label},zlabel={z1 label},xmin=0.65,xmax=0.74]%
        \addplot3[only marks,mark size=0.7pt] table {
            x   y   z   
            0.65    0.31    0.01
            0.66    0.32    0.00
            0.67    0.33    0.03
            0.68    0.34    0.01
            0.69    0.35    0.02
    };
    \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize second figure},xlabel={x2 label},ylabel={y2 label},zlabel={z2 label},xmin=0.65,xmax=0.74]%
        \addplot3[only marks,mark size=0.7pt] table {
            x   y   z   
            0.65    0.55    0.11
            0.65    0.56    0.20
            0.66    0.60    0.33
            0.66    0.58    0.11
            0.66    0.59    0.22
    };
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

How to make x axis label to be red line location which is parallel to the x axis? How to move y axis label to the locaiton of yellow line to parallel the y axis?

[image]

Comment: Adding `sloped` to the options of the *x* and *y* label rotates them properly, repositionig the *y* label works by adding `at={(rel axis cs:0,.5,0)}, above` where `above` just sets the south anchor: `every axis x label/.append style=sloped, every axis y label/.append style={sloped, at={(rel axis cs:0,.5,0)}, above}`? The *z* label has a manual `rotate=90` present which is the reason why that's not horizontal.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. Your way works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
every axis x label/.append style=sloped,
every axis y label/.append style={sloped, at={(rel axis cs: 0, 0.5, 0)}, above},
```

since `sloped` inside the labels stands for [`sloped like ? axis`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-axisdescription#pgfp./tikz/sloped:like:x:axis). This rotates the axis labels appropriately.
Additionally the *y* label gets shifted to the other side via `rel axis cs: 0, 0.5, 0`. The key `above` sets `anchor=south`.

It might make sense to add `anchor=center` to the `every axis x label` style to place it a bit closer.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 1,
    horizontal sep=2cm,
  },
  enlarge x limits=true,
  every axis plot/.append style={only marks, mark size=0.7pt},
  every axis title/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
  every axis label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
  every axis x label/.append style=sloped,
  every axis y label/.append style={sloped, at={(rel axis cs: 0, 0.5, 0)}, above},
  width=7cm, xmin=0.65, xmax=0.74,
]
\nextgroupplot[title=first figure, xlabel={x1 label}, ylabel={y1 label}, zlabel={z1 label}]%
\addplot3 table {
  x   y   z
  0.65    0.31    0.01
  0.66    0.32    0.00
  0.67    0.33    0.03
  0.68    0.34    0.01
  0.69    0.35    0.02
};
\nextgroupplot[title=second figure, xlabel={x2 label}, ylabel={y2 label}, zlabel={z2 label}]%
\addplot3 table {
  x   y   z
  0.65    0.55    0.11
  0.65    0.56    0.20
  0.66    0.60    0.33
  0.66    0.58    0.11
  0.66    0.59    0.22
};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:enter-label}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `every x tick label/.append style=sloped like x axis, every y tick label/.append style=sloped like y axis` would also rotate the tick labels (0.65, 0.7, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6).

Comment: Thanks. `add anchor=center to the every axis x label style to place it a bit closer`, Why? It is weird. When should I use `at={(rel axis cs: 0, 0.5, 0)}` or `at={(0, 0.5, 0)}`?

Comment: Because it usually placed with `anchor=north` (or `below`). The placement algorithms tries to make sure that the axis label doesn't cover the tick labels. When the label is rotated the space looks a bit too big but that's finetuning. The [`at={(rel axis cs: 0, 0.5, 0)}`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-annotations#pgfp.rel:axis:cs) is already included, this shifts the *y* label to the other side.

Comment: Yes. I also found there is too space between **x axis label** and **x tick label**. The default sapce is not perfect.